# Clicking "X" on the ASP.NET popup event

Tags: asp.net

I'm stuck with the question, simple at first glance

Which event raises when we close ASP.NET popup window by clicking "x" in the top right corner?

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in popup control in ASP.NET. There is an ASP.NET AJAX PopupControl, but I don't see anything about an X button. Which control are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This Popup is derived from the UserControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean WinForms event, it would be Form_Closing followed by Form_Closed.  In Asp.Net there's no event that can be caught on the server directly, since this is a client side event.  However, you CAN, in client side script, catch this event ([onUnload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [onbeforeunload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx)) and trigger a postback to the server if you need to.